# reset view window

Tags: modeling

hello I would like to reset the view of the main window in 3D,
In other words, there are occasions where the view is inverted and I look away.
Entocnes: is there any way to reset the 3D view, and return to the view to the original mode?
Thank you.
use blender 2.8

Comment: If you have an object selected you can hit "." on the numpad to focus on that object, you can also press "0" on the numpad to go into camera view, if there is an active camera in your scene. If you have different keymaps go to the top and underneath view click on frame all. These won't reset your view, but they'll at least show your objects.

Comment: In blender 2.8, you can also just add a new "Layout" tab by clicking the plus button in the list of views, and this will create a new tab that has the default view.